# SharePoint 2010 Search results link when clicked should open in a new window

Tags: search-results

SharePoint 2010  Search result link when clicked should open in a new window.
I already know that user can right click and open in a new window

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The HTML that is rendered for the Search results is an outcome of the XSLT transformation that happens on the raw XML returned as Search result. By modifying the XSLT you can achieve your goal

[I found this blog helpful. Hope you too will](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chjain/archive/2012/10/05/sharepoint-how-to-open-sharepoint-search-results-in-a-new-page.aspx)